# which carrier in September had the most late departing flights in nycflights13 dataset

Tags: r

which carrier in September had the most late departing flights in nycflights13 datset

```
q8 <- flights%>%
  select(carrier,month,dep_delay)%>%
  filter(month==9)%>%
  group_by(carrier)%>%
  tally()%>%
  arrange(desc(n))
```

this is the code i used

Answer (score 0):

#### Code Solution

I have provided my code for answering this question with annotations for what each part of the code does. The main issue with your code is that it does not include a way to find whether or not a flight is delayed. Since you are using a numeric variable that can include zero and even negative values (flights sometimes depart early), you cannot simply group it. I show a way below, which is simply to filter for only values greater than 0 (in other words flights that are delayed by at least one minute).

```
flights %>% # take this data
  filter(month == 9, # filter for September
         dep_delay > 0) %>%  # pick only flights with delays
  group_by(carrier) %>% # group by carrier
  count() %>%  # count delayed flights by carrier
  arrange(desc(n)) # arrange in descending order
```

#### Output

The above code gives you this output, showing UA had the most delays for September (n = 1559):

```
# A tibble: 16 × 2
# Groups:   carrier [16]
   carrier     n
   <chr>   <int>
 1 UA       1559
 2 EV       1338
 3 B6       1190
 4 DL        919
 5 AA        709
 6 MQ        556
 7 WN        483
 8 9E        449
 9 US        306
10 VX        142
11 FL        109
12 F9         29
13 YV         16
14 AS          7
15 HA          2
16 OO          1
```